# Transform cluster results dataframe into consensus dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, consensus

I'm working on a consensus clustering project where I run multiple versions of a clustering algorithm on a random subset of my data, and keep track of which items are assigned to which clusters. [This](https://towardsdatascience.com/consensus-clustering-f5d25c98eaf2) article is very similar to what I'm doing. Imagine this process results in the data below.

```
       iter1  iter2  iter3  iter4
Alice      2      0      2      1
Brian      1      1      1      1
Sally      1      2      0      2
James      0      2      1      0
```

The values in this table are the cluster numbers the item has been assigned to in that particular clustering iteration, and 0 when it's excluded from that iteration's clustering (chance for inclusion is 80%). From this DataFrame I would like to calculate the consensus matrix that states how many times two items are in the same cluster, of the iterations in which they were both included. So e.g. Brian and Sally were subsampled together 3 times (iter1, iter2, iter4) but were clustered together twice. Thus, entries for Brian ~ Sally are 0.67 which is approximately 2/3. See the table below for the full consensus matrix.

```
       Alice  Brian  Sally  James
Alice    1.0   0.00   0.00    0.0
Brian    0.0   1.00   0.67    0.5
Sally    0.0   0.67   1.00    1.0
James    0.0   0.50   1.00    1.0
```

My question is: how do I go from the first DataFrame to the second? I imagine one could make the item pairs first by getting all unique items and then making combinations of length 2 (Alice~Brian, Alice~Sally, Alice~James etc) and initialize the empty dataframe so each name is both in the rows and in the columns. Then fill in each cell based on a function that calculates the pair's consensus like we did with Brian ~ Sally (0.67). This, however, already feels kind of cumbersome and I'm fairly sure there is a way better way of doing this. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: I solved this with the following code. I'm not sure if there is a better way (there probably is), but here goes for future reference:

```
# Make the square matrix for N x N
c_matrix = np.zeros(shape=(len(i_table), len(i_table)))
c_matrix[:] = np.NaN  # Replace with NaN to keep the diagonal NaN 
iteration_table = i_table.to_numpy()

# Find all i,j combinations of patients that need a consensus index value
comb = list(combinations(list(range(0, iteration_table.shape[0])), 2))

for c in tqdm(comb):
    both_clustered = 0
    same_cluster = 0

    for i, j in zip(iteration_table[c[0]], iteration_table[c[1]]):
        if i >= 0 and j >= 0:
            both_clustered += 1

            if i == j:
                same_cluster += 1

    res = same_cluster/both_clustered if both_clustered != 0 else 0

    c_matrix[c[0]][c[1]] = res
    c_matrix[c[1]][c[0]] = res
```

Comment: @QuangHoang yes, I edited the post :).

Comment: No, still the second dataframe. I edited your post with the text for `df1`.

Comment: @QuangHoang ah I see like that, thanks!